# For upgrading Azure cache for redis 4 to 6 , Do we need update NuGet Package of StackExchange.Redis also

Tags: redis

For upgrading the `Azure` cache for `Redis v4 to v6`, Do we need to update the NuGet Package of `StackExchange.Redis` also

Comment: which version are you currently using for StackExchange.Redis. because the latest version is 2.6.96

Comment: We are using current version StackExchange.Redis.2.2.4

Upgraded to latest StackExchange.Redis.2.6.96 also 
Is this enough to support Redis 6?

Comment: Please can can you share some steps need to do from code/solution side

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific version compatibility between `Redis` and `StackExchange.Redis` library (see [GitHub link](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1629)). `Azure Redis` and `StackExchange.Redis` are compatible as long as **they are using the same RESP (REdis Serialization Protocol) version.**

Redis version 6 and above supports two protocols: the old protocol, `RESP2`, and a new one introduced with Redis 6, `RESP3`. In Redis 6 connections start in `RESP2` mode, so clients implementing `RESP2` do not need to be updated or changed ([documentation link](https://redis.io/commands/hello/)).

`StackExchange.Redis` library currently does not support `RESP3`, therefore it will default to `RESP2`. It's worth saying that there are [plans to implement RESP3](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/2353) in a future version but these changes are just being discussed and there is no planned release date yet.

So there is no immediate need to update the NuGet package of `StackExchange.Redis` because the underlying protocol has not changed.

I would also recommend asking for Sitecore Support advice before upgrading any dependencies of Sitecore internal libraries. If there are any non-compatibal changes in methods signature in newer versions of `StackExchange.Redis`, you may break internal Sitecore code that relies on this library.