# Getting Compile Error CS1545 after updating StackExchange.Redis

Tags: caching

After updating the NuGet Package of `StackExchange.Redis` latest `2.6.96`

```
error CS1545: Property, indexer, or event 
'ConfigurationOptions.EndPoints' is not supported by the language; 
try directly calling accessor methods 
'ConfigurationOptions.get_EndPoints()' or 
'ConfigurationOptions.set_EndPoints(?)'
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you updated this package? It is usually not recommended to overwrite packages that Sitecore is using. For example 10.3 is using version 2.5.43 of StackExchange.Redis. You can refer to Sitecore Assembly List for specific version https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/103/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_103.aspx.

Comment: Also see this answer for reasons why you should not update `StackExchange.Redis` library https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/34238/for-upgrading-azure-cache-for-redis-4-to-6-do-we-need-update-nuget-package-of/34241#34241

Comment: Can you update your question with some more details like which version you are using for Sitecore to update?

Answer (score 0):

Workarround of the issue is using reflection like this:

```
var cofigurationOptions = new ConfigurationOptions();
var property = typeof(ConfigurationOtions).GetProperty("EndPoints"); // use only literal for property name, otherwise you will get the same error
var endPoints = property.GetValues(cofigurationOptions);

// manupulate with endPoints
```

In my case the reson of this issue is 'init' modificator for property ConfigurationOptions.EndPoint. I suppose that will be the reason of other issues with CS1545 compilation error.